# 2d fft numpy/python confusion

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have data in the form x-y-z and want to create a power spectrum along x-y. Here is a basic example I am posting to check where I might be going wrong with my actual data:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fq = 10; N = 20
x = np.linspace(0,8,N); y = x
space = x[1] -x[0]

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
fnc = np.sin(2*np.pi*fq*xx)
ft = np.fft.fft2(fnc)
ft = np.fft.fftshift(ft)

freq_x  = np.fft.fftfreq(ft.shape[0], d=space)
freq_y  = np.fft.fftfreq(ft.shape[1], d=space)
plt.imshow(
    abs(ft),
    aspect='auto',
    extent=(freq_x.min(),freq_x.max(),freq_y.min(),freq_y.max())
)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(fnc)
```

This results in the following [function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWcN5.png) & [frequency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xooyg.png) figures with the incorrect frequency. Thanks.

Comment: `interpolation='nearest'` will make your result a lot clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your problems is that matplotlib's `imshow` using a different coordinate system to what you expect. Provide a `origin='lower'` argument, and the peaks now appear at `y=0`, as expected.

Another problem that you have is that `fftfreq` needs to be told your timestep, which in your case is `8 / (N - 1)`

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fq = 10; N = 20
x = np.linspace(0,8,N); y = x
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x,y)
fnc = np.sin(2*np.pi*fq*xx)
ft = np.fft.fft2(fnc)
ft = np.fft.fftshift(ft)

freq_x  = np.fft.fftfreq(ft.shape[0], d=8 / (N - 1))  # this takes an argument for the timestep
freq_y  = np.fft.fftfreq(ft.shape[1], d=8 / (N - 1))
plt.imshow(
    abs(ft),
    aspect='auto',
    extent=(freq_x.min(),freq_x.max(),freq_y.min(),freq_y.max()),
    origin='lower' ,          # this fixes your problem
    interpolation='nearest',  # this makes it easier to see what is happening
    cmap='viridis'            # let's use a better color map too
)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

You may say *"but the frequency is 10, not 0.5!"* However, if you want to sample a frequency of `10`, you need to sample a lot faster than `8/19`! Nyquist's theorem says you need to **exceed** a sampling rate of 20 to have any hope at all

Comment: any ideas, how I can get rid of stuff above the Nyquist f, i.e. obtain the single frequency only? Thanks.

Comment: @user6769140: You already got rid of that stuff - the nyquist frequency is 20, yet in the plot above your graph only reaches ~1.2